CIFilter chain failing to render parts of output
I’ve built a iOS camera app that applies many CIFilters to an image captured by the camera. Some of my users have reported that on occasion the images have large parts that are blank, see below:

Frustratingly, I can’t reproduce this myself! Does anyone know what could he causing it, is it a memory issue? I haven’t posted the code as there’s a lot to look over and I’m not sure it would help diagnose it.
Thanks for any pointers.

Do you use any custom CIFilters?

No, only the built ins.

looks like multithreaded/GPU processing that just stopped before it was done. do these APIs have any kind of timeouts in them? anything that limits the usage of compute resources?

Thanks I’ll look into that! I don’t think they have any time outs but there’s a chance if they’re taking multiple photos in a row there could be an issue.

if you do any processing in the GUI thread (event handlers), the system might kill you for that. test your app with low-powered devices.

I am running the function in a thread within: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated

How large are the images you are processing? If you apply image scaling somewhere in the pipeline, consider moving it to the front of the pipeline.

@FrankRupprecht I’m processing 12MP images, not scaling down.

Do you know what devices the issue is appearing on? Can you please elaborate a bit on the filters you are applying?

Sorry I'm not sure on what devices. The chain is quite complex, thanks for your help tho!
